# Is comparing the same string literals always true?

Tags: c, string

In C language, is compiler/linker obligated to put the same *string literal* used multiple times into single memory location?

```
const char* a = "abcdef";
const char* b = "abcdef";

//Compare pointers
if (a == b) {
    printf("True\r\n");
} else {
    printf("False\r\n");
}
```

In this case, is statement above always true (in MSVC 2017 it is) or is it *undefined behavior* in general?

Can it happen that we have string literal `abcdef` in `2` different memory locations? Of course, I do not count strings like `12abcdefgh`˛where `abcdef` is part of string, but standalone.

Comment: It depends on compiler options. Whether to merge duplicate definitions.

Comment: I think *undefined behavior* is a misnomer here. The behavior of the program is well defined in that it will print either "True" or "False" (as opposed to segfault, format your hard drive, etc)

Comment: implemented behavior, clearly don't assume that in your program.

Comment: Comparing pointer which don't point to (or exactly past) the same array is undefined behaviour.

Comment: No, the compiler is not required to map multiple instances of a string literal to the same location.  See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), 6.4.5/7.

Answer (score 2):

What you are comparing here are  *pointers* to the string literals. String literals are statically allocated in some memory, which is not supposed to be written. An optimizing compiler *might* allocate the same string literal only once since it is assuming these will never change and there is no point of having more than a single copy, and this is what you are observing here. But it is not guaranteed.

Comment: It can also perform other transformations for deduplicating string literal content. For example, `"hello world"+6 == "world"` might be true.

Comment: @R.. That is something I've never seen.. (maybe because never checked :) )

Comment: To be clear, the comment fom @R.. is not a string comparison, but a pointer comparison.

Comment: @WeatherVane: There's no such thing as "string comparison" in C, unless you mean `strcmp`, and of course `strcmp("hello world"+6, "world")==0` is always true.

Comment: @R.. obviously, that is what I thought ***you*** meant. I was enlarging on your true but unclear comment.

Comment: it will be only the truth in this trivial example if you change the type of one of the variables two copies of the literal will be placed in the `.rodata` section.  Example: `const char *a = "abcdef";
const char b[] = "abcdef";`

Comment: @P__J__: I think what you're saying is that named objects have unique addresses/cannot coincide, and that's correct. String literals are special in that they need not have unique addresses.

Comment: Actually the compilers in this case duplicate the literal. Theoretically it is not necessary: one vatiable keeps the reference, another the copy.

Answer (score 1):

It is unspecified behavior but most compilers will optimize this such that it is true.  If you are coding to a specific compiler, you may find a switch or `#pragma` that controls folding such strings and therefore give you something deterministic.

Comment: "undefined behaviour" is the wrong term; I suppose behaviour here is "implementation defined"

Comment: @StephanLechner As long as we're nitpicking, it's actually "unspecified behavior". See annex J.1 and section 6.4.5.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that any *particular* string literal used within the code (after macro expansion) will always have a constant address, e.g. that given `inline char const *foo(void) { return "Hey";}`, every call to `foo` within a translation unit would yield the same address?

Comment: yes, string literals are constant addresses of arrays that contain the characters followed by a NUL terminator